# Recovering from zmq.error.Again on a zmq.PAIR socket

Tags: python, networking, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a single client talking to a single server using a pair socket:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SNDTIMEO, 1000)
socket.connect("tcp://%s:%i"%(host,port))
```

...

```
if msg != None:
    try:
        socket.send(msg)
    except Exception as e:
         print(e, e.errno)
```

The program sends approximately one 10-byte message every second. We were seeing issues where the program would eventually start to hang infinitely waiting for a message to send, so we added a SNDTIMEO. However, now we are starting to get zmq.error.Again instead. Once we get this error, the resource never becomes available again. I'm looking into which error code exactly is occurring, but I was generally wondering what techniques people use to recover from zmq.error.Again inside their programs. Should I destroy the socket connection and re-establish it?

Answer (score 1):

### Fact#0: `PAIR/PAIR` is different from other ZeroMQ archetypes

RFC 31 explicitly defines:

> **Overall Goals of this Pattern**
>
> **`PAIR`** is not a general-purpose socket but is intended for specific use cases where the two peers are architecturally stable. This usually limits **`PAIR`** to use within a single process, for inter-thread communication.

Next, if not correctly set the **`SNDHWM`** size and in case of the will to use the `PAIR` to operate over **`tcp://`**-transport-class also all the O/S-related L3/L2-attributed, any next **`.send()`** will also yield **`EAGAIN`** error.

There are a few additional counter-measures ( **`CONFLATE`**, **`IMMEDIATE`**, **`HEARTBEAT_{IVL|TTL|TIMEOUT}`** ), but there is the above mentioned principal limit on `PAIR/PAIR`, which sets what not to expect to happen if using this archetype.

---

### The main suspect:

Given the said design-side limits, a damaged transport-path, the **`PAIR`**-access-point will not re-negotiate the reconstruction of the socket into the RTO-state.

For this reason, if your code indeed wants to remain using `PAIR/PAIR`, it may be wise to assemble also an emergency SIG/flag path so as to allow the [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) robustly survive such L3/L2/L1-incidents, that the `PAIR/PAIR` is known not to auto-take care of.

---

## Epilogue:

your code does not use non-blocking `.send()`-mode, while the **`EAGAIN`** error-state is exactly used to signal a blocked-capability ( unability of the Access-Point to `.send()` at this very moment ) by setting the `EAGAIN`.

Better use the published API details:

```
aRetCODE = -1 # _______________________________________ PRESET
try:
   aRetCODE = socket.send( msg, zmq.DONTWAIT ) #_______ .SET on RET
   if ( aRetCODE == -1 ):
        ...                                    # ZeroMQ: SIG'd via ERRNO:

except:
   ...                                         #_______ .HANDLE EXC
finally:
   ...
```

Comment: I see. I've experimented with manually bringing the network interface down for 30-60s, and the program gives a Resource Temporarily Unavailable message, but then recovers. So I am not sure what is happening with the longer sessions that is unrecoverable.

The main reason I went with PAIR/PAIR was that at the time we were prototyping this software a few months ago, RADIO/DISH and CLIENT/SERVER were still in early draft for pyzmq. Now that those drafts are more stable, do you think it is worth trying to switch to that paradigm? Would it help with the Resource Temporarily Unavailable messages?

Comment: Well, the native API evolves under the hood of the pyzmq. Given the initial versions of PAIR/PAIR were since inception labeled "experimental" and "for inter-thread communications", be rather careful on field deployment, where one has zero-warranty what would be the API version of the remote peer(s). A complete resource-management + error-detection + robust error-recovery strategy is a standard bread & butter in **[tag:distributed-system]**. RADIO/DISH seem to me to be just a re-labeled PUB/SUB Scalable Formal Communication Archetype, se best re-read the native API 4.2+ details.

Comment: The noted tcp://-transport-class establisher PAIR/PAIR end-to-end SIG/MSG communication channel recovery seems to be a new feature, established in a newer native API version, this was explicitly rejected in older API versions. In those days, when a [tag:distributed-system] system had to expand from localhost-only, the PAIR/PAIR used to be rather replaced by tandem of simplex PUSH/PULL archetypes, or the absenting features of the PAIR/PAIR were similarly circumvented.